# How to update document changes after infinite scroll adds new items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems with dom changes.

I have 20 `li` elements in my parent `ul`. I have changed all `li` content using the following jquery code:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.signature-discount')].map(item => item.innerHTML = '<span class=\"discount-value\">new content</span>');
$(".product-detail").append("<span class='signature-info'>more new content</span>");
```

In the page that the `li` are located there is a infinite scroll. The problem is that everytime the user scrolls to the bottom, 20 new elements are added but their content are not affected by my jquery code.

I have tried using `DOMSubtreeModified` to listen to changes to my `ul` classname but it did not work as expected. Can you guys help me? The answer can be either jquery or plain javascript.

Comment: Selectors and event handlers specified at page load will only match elements which exist at page load. You are adding new elements *after* page load, and your event listeners will not match them - jQuery doesn't know about those new elements.  You need to delegate your handlers to an element that exists at load, and filter to match only your target elements.  This is a very common problem, and there are many duplicates and variations here on SO, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: It doenst. This is considering an onClick event, which I don't have. I just append a new content to my DOM and thats it. No interaction from the user besides scrolling. @Don'tPanic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it :)

Since my scenario had no user interaction like most questions about this topic here in SO, I had to watch the user scroll and check the length of my li's.

If the length is bigger than the initial value, then it will re-apply my JS changes.

```
let initialLength = 20; //this is my initial li length items
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".liProduct").length > initialLength) {
        initialLength = document.querySelectorAll(".liProduct").length; //defining a new initialLength to keep the loop going
        [...document.querySelectorAll('.signature-discount')].map(item => item.innerHTML = '<span class=\"discount-value\">new content</span>');
        $(".product-detail").append("<span class='signature-info'>new content 2</span>");
    }
});
```